# Oxygen condensation on Earth

Tags: atmospheric-science, weather, climate-science, condensation

I am getting interesting results using the Clausius-Clapeyron relation to calculate the saturation vapour pressure of diatomic oxygen. I am using the following values:

- 214kJ/kg for latent heat of vaporization
- 54K/146Pa (oxygen triple point) as T0 and e0

With this I calculated that the saturation pressure is about 30kPa at 273K, and about 10kPa at 200K.

Assuming that the right CCN for diatomic oxygen are present, does this mean that if Earth had a higher concentration of oxygen (>30%), it could condense high up in Earth's atmosphere?

Comment: https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/40/jresv40n6p457_A1b.pdf has PVT data for oxygen gas.

Comment: Or https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6753035/

Comment: Looks like I was using the wrong units, now it makes more sense. Thanks!